# Search/Filter OneNote content gives error "OData Syntax error"

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I want to search `data-tag="to-do"` across several pages in OneNote API. I am using the following code with Access toke in headers through curl --

```
$url = "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes";
$url .= "/pages?filter=data-tag%20eq%20'to-do'";
```

But it is giving me this error --

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"20128","message":"OData Syntax error at position 5 in 'data-tag eq 'to-do''.","@api.url":"http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20128"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

data-tag is not a field you can filter on in the pages entity, therefore $filter won't work. You can try searching page content (fulltext search) via ?search=[YOURSEARCHSTRING]. Fulltext search however is not the right way of filtering for certain types of page content, like data tags.

I encourage you to enter an item for us in our uservoice, as there is no direct way of searching this content (other than querying every page and parsing its results)

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis